# Is this error "invalid context...fatal error" due to GRASS GIS bug or the system?

Tags: grass-gis, error

Copy of error message that appears in the terminal (Macbook Pro, OS X 10.9.5):

> MacBook-Pro.local Python[2653] :CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.

What could cause this? Can I ignore it? I'm importing Lidar data into GRASS, and the application completes the process without an error in the application's command window.

Comment: To me this looks like a question better asked/researched at [su] because I would suspect system before GRASS based on the symptoms you observed.

Comment: Hard to say without knowing which GRASS GIS version you are using... we had such an issue in the past which got fixed since then.

Comment: I'm using GRASS 7.1. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: @nmill137 I'm having the same issue.  Did you find a solution?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is either a bug report and hence, not a question for GIS.SE; as recommended in our GIS Meta post [What should we do with bug reports?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4185/what-should-we-do-with-bug-reports) or it's a system issue which is also off-topic as [mentioned by PolyGeo](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/147870/is-this-error-invalid-context-fatal-error-due-to-grass-gis-bug-or-the-system#comment215972_147870).